# check that contenteditable div is empty or not

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a content-editable div that works as Textarea.

```
<div id="divThatYouCanWriteStuffIn" contenteditable="true" class="ibox-content col-lg-12">
</div>
```

Now I want check whether this div is empty or not, for validations.

What I used is as below.

```
 if ($('#divThatYouCanWriteStuffIn')[0].innerText == "") {
        alert("Please update your wall, then post.")
        return false;
  }
```

But it's not working if user just clicked enter in div. Same way I have used

```
 if ($('#divThatYouCanWriteStuffIn')[0].innerText.length <= 1) {
        alert("Please update your wall, then post.")
        return false;
    }

$('#divThatYouCanWriteStuffIn').html()
```

But it also has break tags inside div, as it takes blank as break

So, is there any way to check that editable div is not empty and has some proper text?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/k2667f5q/

Comment: FYI, by definition, any white space makes it not empty. What you want is to trim its content. BUT what about any empty/void HTML element inside this contenteditable `div`? Are you considering it as empty or not???  Now why don't you use a textarea? `contenteditable` cannot be used as teaxtarea replacement for many many reasons, especially because different browser support/behaviour

Comment: @A.Wolff first i cannot use textarea as it width is fixed..and second if there is no text then all html tags not needed so, it must act as blank..and thanks for your support.

Comment: @Bharat `first i cannot use textarea as it width is fixed..` I'm not sure what you mean?! `.and second if there is no text then all html tags not needed so, it must act as blank..` Still, i don't understand what you mean?! Can you provide concrete sample replicating your issue compare to expected behaviour?

Comment: sure..................

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `text()` method to get the relevant content(content without html tags)

```
  if ($('#divThatYouCanWriteStuffIn').text().trim().length == 0) {
    alert("empty");
  }
```

`.trim()` function removes all the white spaces and newline characters from the beginning and end of the content.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv5cn8xy/217/)

Comment: Do add about `.trim()` as well ;)

Comment: @Rayon added. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: yes, i am...but really you think you need more reputations?

Comment: @AnoopJoshi yepp, that's true...just wondering how a person can get that mush repo.

Answer (score 2):

Incase your contenteditable `div` contains html. I used this method below

```
divHtml = $('div#divThatYouCanWriteStuffIn').html();
checkEmpty = divHtml.replace(' ', '').replace('<br>', '');
if(checkEmpty.length == 0){
    alert('empty');
}
```

Replace all space with nothing and all line breaks `<br>` with nothing also

Comment: @Bharat this should be the accepted answer as it takes none text (html elements) into consideration also